# Program get stuck for Heart Rate, SpO2, Temperature monitoring using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am trying to make an Arduino Project which can measure Body Temperature, Heart Rate & SpO2 using MLX90614, VL53L0X & MAXREFDES117# sensors respectively with Arduino Uno

For Heartrate and SpO2 output i am using program and algorithm modifies by RF Master whose github link is
https://github.com/aromring/MAX30102_by_RF/blob/master/ExpectedGoodQualitySignals.csv

For Temperature measurement i am using MAX90614 with LV53L0X LIDAR sensor for range monitoring.
For the above combined output i am using ADAFRUIT libraries.
And i am getting desired output from both these sensor when combined together in a program.

**I have edited the ode to the best of my knowledge. I have two programs now, in one programe (PR1) when i take input from user then my hear rate sensor stops after taking 100 readings but does not give an output where as temperature and LIDAR works fine
On the othe program (PR2) when i set condition to run only heart rate program then it gives and output using `bool hr= true/false` independantly**

Need help to get the heart rate output when user input is taken.
Please help.

Regards
Shubhashish

Program (PR1)

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "algorithm_by_RF.h"
#include "max30102.h"
#include <VL53L0X.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();
VL53L0X sensor;
const byte oxiInt = 10;
uint32_t elapsedTime,timeStart;
uint32_t aun_ir_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint32_t aun_red_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
float old_n_spo2;
uint8_t uch_dummy,k;
bool hr=true;
uint8_t ip = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  
  Serial.println(F("1. Heart Rate\n2. Temp"));
  while(Serial.available()==0)  //wait until user presses a key
  ip = Serial.parseInt();
    if(ip==1) {hr = true;}  else {hr=false;}
  
  if(hr)
  {
    pinMode(oxiInt, INPUT);
    Wire.begin();
    maxim_max30102_reset();
    delay(1000);

    maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_1,&uch_dummy);  //Reads/clears the interrupt status register
    maxim_max30102_init();  //initialize the MAX30102
    old_n_spo2=0.0;
  } 
  else
  {
  mlx.begin();
  Wire.begin();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);
  if (!sensor.init())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to detect and initialize sensor!");
    while (1) {}
  }
    sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(200000); 
    Serial.print(sensor.readRangeSingleMillimeters());
    Serial.print(F("*F\tObject = ")); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempF());Serial.println(F("*F"));
  if (sensor.timeoutOccurred()) { Serial.print(" TIMEOUT"); }
    delay(100);
    
  }
  
  if(hr)
  {
    uch_dummy=Serial.read();
    Serial.print(F("Time[s]\tSpO2\tHR\tClock\tRatio\tCorr\t"));
    timeStart=millis();
  }
}

void loop() {
  if(hr)
  {
    float n_spo2,ratio,correl;
    int8_t ch_spo2_valid;
    int32_t n_heart_rate;
    int8_t  ch_hr_valid;
    int32_t i;
    char hr_str[10];
    delay(1000);
    for(i=0;i<BUFFER_SIZE;i++)
    {
      while(digitalRead(oxiInt)==1);  //wait until the interrupt pin asserts
      maxim_max30102_read_fifo((aun_red_buffer+i), (aun_ir_buffer+i));  //read from MAX30102 FIFO

      Serial.print(i, DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(aun_red_buffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.println(aun_ir_buffer[i], DEC);    
    }

    rf_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(aun_ir_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, aun_red_buffer, &n_spo2, &ch_spo2_valid, &n_heart_rate, &ch_hr_valid, &ratio, &correl); 
    elapsedTime=millis()-timeStart;
    millis_to_hours(elapsedTime,hr_str);
    elapsedTime/=1000;

    Serial.println(F("--RF--"));
    Serial.print(elapsedTime);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(n_spo2);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(n_heart_rate, DEC);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.println(hr_str);
    Serial.println(F("------"));

    if(ch_hr_valid && ch_spo2_valid)
    {
      Serial.print(elapsedTime);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(n_spo2);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(n_heart_rate, DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(hr_str);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(ratio);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(correl);
      old_n_spo2=n_spo2;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    while(1) { }
   
  }
}

void millis_to_hours(uint32_t ms, char* hr_str)
{
  char istr[6];
  uint32_t secs,mins,hrs;
  secs=ms/1000; // time in seconds
  mins=secs/60; // time in minutes
  secs-=60*mins; // leftover seconds
  hrs=mins/60; // time in hours
  mins-=60*hrs; // leftover minutes
  itoa(hrs,hr_str,10);
  strcat(hr_str,":");
  itoa(mins,istr,10);
  strcat(hr_str,istr);
  strcat(hr_str,":");
  itoa(secs,istr,10);
  strcat(hr_str,istr);
}
```

Output of PR1 when user selected heart rate

```
1. Heart Rate 
2. Temp
Time[s] SpO2    HR  Clock   Ratio   Corr    0   737 508
1   731 511
2   733 507
3   734 506
4   728 504
5   734 506
6   738 503
7   736 505
8   731 507
9   741 503
10  739 516
11  733 508
12  734 512
13  735 507
14  730 507
15  732 494
16  741 502
17  734 509
18  728 502
19  742 505
20  742 500
21  736 502
22  742 501
23  734 508
24  735 508
25  733 506
26  734 505
27  732 507
28  732 498
29  737 505
30  736 504
31  729 502
32  731 498
33  730 502
34  733 507
35  730 502
36  730 508
37  729 504
38  729 505
39  731 505
40  730 500
41  731 497
42  733 498
43  733 505
44  736 504
45  730 501
46  731 505
47  733 506
48  734 505
49  732 498
50  735 502
51  736 499
52  731 499
53  729 507
54  729 506
55  728 504
56  734 499
57  729 509
58  734 503
59  727 507
60  736 501
61  730 505
62  735 501
63  734 507
64  731 508
65  732 503
66  731 503
67  736 506
68  731 502
69  738 512
70  736 506
71  734 504
72  735 505
73  733 506
74  733 503
75  730 506
76  730 502
77  732 508
78  731 502
79  734 508
80  733 505
81  727 504
82  742 508
83  735 506
84  738 503
85  729 504
86  729 505
87  728 502
88  726 512
89  729 502
90  734 503
91  737 499
92  732 510
93  739 503
94  734 512
95  731 510
96  734 499
97  738 503
98  729 505
99  724 510
03
    734 512
    731 510
    734 499
AA1. Heart Rate
2. Temp
```

Output of PR1 when user selected temp

```
1. Heart Rate
2. Temp
70*F    Object = 85.26*F
```

Program PR2

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "algorithm_by_RF.h"
#include "max30102.h"
#include <VL53L0X.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();
VL53L0X sensor;
const byte oxiInt = 10;
uint32_t elapsedTime,timeStart;
uint32_t aun_ir_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint32_t aun_red_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
float old_n_spo2;
uint8_t uch_dummy,k;
bool hr=false;
//uint8_t ip = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  
  //Serial.println(F("1. Heart Rate\n2. Temp"));
  /*while(Serial.available()==0)  //wait until user presses a key
  {
    ip = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  if(ip==1) {hr = true;}*/
  
  if(hr)
  {
    pinMode(oxiInt, INPUT);
    Wire.begin();
    maxim_max30102_reset();
    delay(1000);

    maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_1,&uch_dummy);  //Reads/clears the interrupt status register
    maxim_max30102_init();  //initialize the MAX30102
    old_n_spo2=0.0;
  } 
  else
  {
    mlx.begin();
    Wire.begin();
    sensor.setTimeout(500);
  if (!sensor.init())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to detect and initialize sensor!");
    while (1) {}
  }
    sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(200000); 
    
    
  }
  
  if(hr)
  {
    uch_dummy=Serial.read();
    Serial.print(F("Time[s]\tSpO2\tHR\tClock\tRatio\tCorr\t"));
    timeStart=millis();
  }
}

void loop() {
  if(hr)
  {
    float n_spo2,ratio,correl;
    int8_t ch_spo2_valid;
    int32_t n_heart_rate;
    int8_t  ch_hr_valid;
    int32_t i;
    char hr_str[10];
    delay(1000);
    for(i=0;i<BUFFER_SIZE;i++)
    {
      while(digitalRead(oxiInt)==1);  //wait until the interrupt pin asserts
      maxim_max30102_read_fifo((aun_red_buffer+i), (aun_ir_buffer+i));  //read from MAX30102 FIFO

      Serial.print(i, DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(aun_red_buffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.println(aun_ir_buffer[i], DEC);    
    }

    rf_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(aun_ir_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, aun_red_buffer, &n_spo2, &ch_spo2_valid, &n_heart_rate, &ch_hr_valid, &ratio, &correl); 
    elapsedTime=millis()-timeStart;
    millis_to_hours(elapsedTime,hr_str);
    elapsedTime/=1000;

    Serial.println(F("--RF--"));
    Serial.print(elapsedTime);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(n_spo2);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(n_heart_rate, DEC);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.println(hr_str);
    Serial.println(F("------"));

    if(ch_hr_valid && ch_spo2_valid)
    {
      Serial.print(elapsedTime);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(n_spo2);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(n_heart_rate, DEC);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(hr_str);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(ratio);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      Serial.print(correl);
      old_n_spo2=n_spo2;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(sensor.readRangeSingleMillimeters());
     Serial.print(F("*F\tObject = ")); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempF());Serial.println(F("*F"));
  if (sensor.timeoutOccurred()) { Serial.print(" TIMEOUT"); }
      delay(100);
  }
}

void millis_to_hours(uint32_t ms, char* hr_str)
{
  char istr[6];
  uint32_t secs,mins,hrs;
  secs=ms/1000; // time in seconds
  mins=secs/60; // time in minutes
  secs-=60*mins; // leftover seconds
  hrs=mins/60; // time in hours
  mins-=60*hrs; // leftover minutes
  itoa(hrs,hr_str,10);
  strcat(hr_str,":");
  itoa(mins,istr,10);
  strcat(hr_str,istr);
  strcat(hr_str,":");
  itoa(secs,istr,10);
  strcat(hr_str,istr);
}
```

***This program give me output for heart rate when i set*** `bool hr= true`
*** And gives me output for temp and distance when i set*** `bool hr=false`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It is rather unlikely that anyone will download a library and wade through tons of code. You should remove everything possible from your sample.

Comment: i have reduced the program to the best of my ability. i am geting output for each individual sensor. As far as i can understand the problem doesnot lie in the library but in my code or thr arduino processing power. it seems the code is overwhelming the microcontroller

Comment: You should definitely clean up the code a bit, formatting is way off also what you have posted is not even valid, missing at least BUFFER_SIZE and closing brace of loop().

Comment: Your array in the millis_to_hours routine is not large enough and will overflow.  2 digits for seconds, two for minutes, at least one for hours, and two colons makes for 7 characters.  Plus you need room for a terminator.  So you need at least 8 and you need 9 if hours can be double digits.

Comment: @r-ahlskog : the buffer size is taken from algorith_by_RF.h its a product of ST (sec) and FS (samples per second) ```BUFFER_SIZE=ST*FS``` where ST=4 sec and FS= 25 samples per second. giving a total of 100 reading from the Heart Rate sensor. the no. of reading is same as in the 1st ouput data that i have provided.

Comment: @r-ahlskog :For the brace of loop i checked and you were right but program runs without any problem, i think this is because some logical correction that the compiler makes, as the code ```if(ch_hr_valid && ch_spo2_valid || ch_hr_valid_maxim && ch_spo2_valid_maxim) { ``` does not require a open brace as after this code there is an else statement. So i beleive the compiler identifies the closing braces for the loop().

Comment: @ Delta_G i increased the array size as per your recomendation but there was no change.

Comment: i have made a video comprising of the sensor and the corresponding output that i am getting. I beleive it will help in better understanding of my problem. the link to the video is https://youtu.be/ufl-eJPT-yk

Comment: It feels like you make be using delay() in a manner that won't allow you to properly service your interrupts, in particular in your `temperature()` function.  If anything else needs to happen (serial management, polling of other devices, etc., it will be ignored if that delay() is a full on CPU sleep.  Typically, ISR routines handle when data is available and quickly place it in a shared location then return.  My bet is the other sensors are being starved by that delay().

Comment: @Michael Dorgan I reduced  delay( ) to 100 milli seconds but it dint had any effect .

Comment: I even tried to put the seperate functions for ```temeprature()``` and ```heart rate()``` and called them in the ```loop()``` using if command and input from user but still no success

Comment: @Gerhardh  i have edited the program and i think it has improved from before, but still i am not getting an output from the Heart Rate monitor

Comment: @Delta_G  i have edited the program and i think it has improved from before, but still i am not getting an output from the Heart Rate monitor

Comment: @r_ahlskog   i have edited the program and i think it has improved from before, but still i am not getting an output from the Heart Rate monitor

Comment: @MichaelDorgan i have edited the program and i think it has improved from before, but still i am not getting an output from the Heart Rate monitor

Comment: Can you get the heart rate monitor working on its own and then the 3rd device?  That will at least verify that your code is working for them before jumbling them together.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yes i can get the heart rate monitor working on its own. If you see the program PR2, i have just commented out the code which takes input from user. And if i set ```bool hr=true``` it will run the Hear rate code and will give an output and if i set ```bool hr = false``` then i get output from the temperature sensor. The heart rate sensor is getting stuck only when i take a user input which is in the program PR1. Individually both the sensor are giving output

Comment: Can you use threads?